# Log4j2 empty disk space

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, log4j2, diskspace

i am using `log4j2` over `slf4j` and encounter an issue when disk space is empty.

my configuration is : Everything is **Async** loggers and **RollingFile** appenders with size trigger of **20mb**.

when empty disk space happens , it seems the application just get stuck, no logs are being created which is obviously, but also API calls are not being responded.

suggestions ?

Comment: "suggestions ?" - Do not run out of disk space ... it is not the responsibility of the application nor the logging subsystem to detect low storage. You can use some server monitoring utility for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did.
The idea is to contain the total possible disk space used by log4j2 just like max heap for JVM. So I used a size based policy along with a max rollover for all the appenders.

If it works as expected then you shouldn't be using more than 10GB per appender at anytime since the log4j2 also uses some compression on rolled over files.

eg.

```
<Policies>
   <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 GB" /> 
...
<Policies>
...
<DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
```